# Where is this Star Wars image from?

Tags: star-wars, image-identification

I found this image on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-biggest-flaws-in-Star-Wars-films/answer/Sasha-An%C4%91eli%C4%87?ch=10&share=3e5820ec&srid=2KT2):

[image]

What is the original source of this image? Google reverse image search didn't help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an image of [Despayre](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Despayre) from *[Star Wars: The Essential Chronology](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Chronology)*.

It's captioned "*Slavery on Despayre*" and was an original illustration by Bill Hughes,

[image]
Higher quality (uncropped)

Comment: Star Wars naming schemes haven't gotten any better, I see..

Comment: That Vader's hand though...